# seamless texture in blender

Tags: texturing

i would like to create seamless texture directly in blender,  is there a manner to do it, i tried with offset but the tiling seams not working,may be i do wrong and also in photoshop to blend texture better there's the content-aware feature, is there a similar thing i can do in blender. I  use photoshop, but i would like only use blender. Making seamless textures in blender would be great no? but is it possible, I'm very beginner, so forgive me if the question seems stupid

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15085/how-can-a-texture-converted-to-be-tileable-seamless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your brush settings, activate Tiling (X  and Y). Now when the brush go past the left of the texture, it continue to draw on the right seamlessely.

In the Properties of the Image Editor, you can check Display/Coordinates/Repeat. Now the texture repeats itself on both axis, and it's easy to see if it is seamless.